# How to make intent data saved when changing Activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my first activity i will pass my data base from firebase into the 2nd activity.

```
private void isUser() {


        final String userEnteredUsername = username.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        final String userEnteredPassword = password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(userEnteredUsername);

        checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    username.setError(null);
                    username.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    String passwordFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("password").getValue(String.class);
                    if(passwordFromDB.equals(userEnteredPassword)){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfilePage.class);
                        String nameFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("name").getValue(String.class);
                        String usernameFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("username").getValue(String.class);
                        String phoneNoFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("phoneNo").getValue(String.class);
                        String emailFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("email").getValue(String.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name", nameFromDB);
                        intent.putExtra("username", usernameFromDB);
                        intent.putExtra("email", emailFromDB);
                        intent.putExtra("phoneNo", phoneNoFromDB);
                        intent.putExtra("password", passwordFromDB);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        

                    } else {
                        password.setError("Wrong Password");
                        password.requestFocus();
                    }
                } else {
                    username.setError("No such User exist");
                    username.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

How i make my intent data save? When i change activity from my 2nd activity the data will be gone. How do i make it so that it will the data will be save in my activity. I have tried multiple ways. shared preference, retriving the data again from firebase and adding super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState) coding but non of the seem to work.

```
private void showAllUserData() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        _USERNAME = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        _NAME = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        _EMAIL = intent.getStringExtra("email");
        _PHONENO = intent.getStringExtra("phoneNo");
        _PASSWORD = intent.getStringExtra("password");

        fullNameLabel.setText(_NAME);
        usernameLabel.setText(_USERNAME);
        fullName.getEditText().setText(_NAME);
        email.getEditText().setText(_EMAIL);
        phoneNo.getEditText().setText(_PHONENO);
        password.getEditText().setText(_PASSWORD);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your datasnapshot contain the strings your're expecting? Maybe the fields you want are null or blank on the datasnapshot

Answer (score 0):

onSaveInstanceState only called when activity is destroyed, your activity may just be paused. Using shared preference, you should be able to share that data. If that still does work, try to declare those fields as public static in one activity and share data that way.